# Parse: How can I reduce query time in php

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am working on an app and as the app grows, so does my query.
**The Problem:**
It takes 14 seconds for a set of queries in a particular function to execute

```
  public function doQuery($venueId){

  //creating an outlet object using the outlet id.
  $outlet = new ParseObject("Outlets", $venueId);

  //querying for total amount of beacons
  $beacQuery = new ParseQuery("Beacons");
  $beacQuery->equalTo("outlet", $outlet);
  $beacresults = $beacQuery->count();

  //querying for outlets based on id
  //I can't do this by simply calling get() on the object
  //I created earlier
  $outletQuery = new ParseQuery("Outlets");
  $outletQuery->equalTo("objectId", $venueId);
  $outletQuery->includeKey("city.states");
  $outletQuery->includeKey("city.states.country");
  $compResults = $outletQuery->find();

  $outletInfo = [];

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($compResults); $i++) {
      $object = $compResults[$i];
      $cityCheck = $object->get("city");
      $statesCheck = $cityCheck->get("states");
      $countryCheck = $statesCheck->get("country");
      $city = $cityCheck->get("Cities");
      $state = $statesCheck->get("stateName");
      $country = $countryCheck->get("countryName");
      $outletInfo[] =   ['venueName' => $object->get('outletName'),
                        'venueAddr' => $object->get('address').', '.$city.', '.$state.', '.$country,
                        'venueEmail' => $object->get('email'),
                        'venueId' => $object->getObjectId(),
                        'totalBeac' => $beacresults,
                    ];
  }
  return $outletInfo;
}
```

I need to know if there is a way to simplify the query to reduce query time and make the page load faster (slow loading is not good for user experience).

Comment: `EXPLAIN` the query, see how it is being executed, then index the appropriate columns.

Comment: Do what @twentylemon said and run `EXPLAIN` after that again.

Comment: is indexing possible on parse? @twentylemon

Comment: The above comments assume your question is about SQL, which it isn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really log some profiling information so you can see what it taking the most time. Primarily you will most likely want to change the data model to increase speed, particularly the count. It's more efficient to keep a count variable updated than it is to search for and count the items. It looks like you can add a count of beacons to each outlet and keep that updated in a save hook in cloud code (though you need to verify that this logic matches what you need).

Also, your `find()` should really be a `get()`, because you have the `objectId` so you know there will only ever be 1 result. This will simplify your code and allow parse to run more efficiently (they may have a check internally, they may not, but you can help speed the process in any event).

Comment: I fixed it though. I did a benchmark on the code and found out that it took just 1.1seconds to execute, I kept on with the checks and saw a little redundant code somewhere which was actually the problem(I'm using the codeIgniter framework). Your answer got me close to the solution, Thank you.